# DDms is not opened sometimes

Tags: android, ddms

In my system sometimes ddms (dalvik debugger) tool sometimes doesn't open. What is the problem? And what can I do for this problem? When I open it through command prompt it displays the following error:

> 38:16 E/DeviceMonitor: Failed to read the adb response!
>   38:24 E/DeviceMonitor: Failed to read the adb response!

What can I do?

Comment: Are you saying it fails to open when you type `ddms` at the command line? If you do that, what console errors do you see? Edit your original question and paste the console output of that command to get some better answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I get problems attaching the debugger to a device. Running this from the command line can fix it.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Also, running more than one version of Eclipse (or Eclipse plus the DDMS tool itself) can result in problems (you get warnings about this now I believe).